# OpengGL face culing for selected faces

Tags: opengl

I'm importing geometry data from a file and the objects could be split in two categories: open or closed.

If all of them were closed, I could just cull the backfaces, but since some of them are not closed, I cannot, because the user could see only the front faces.

I know if an object is open or closed. So the question is, can I do something like enable face culling, draw all closed objects then disable face culling and draw the open meshes?

If the answer is no, which of these would result in better performance?

1. Disable face culling and render all triangles with both faces
2. Enable face culling and draw 2 triangles (one CW and other CCW) for the meshes that aren't closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable face culling just for some of the objects. Since OpenGL is a state machine, from the moment when you call glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) all objects are culled. When you disable it, nothing is called anymore. So for your case you will have to do something similar to:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
//Draw all closed objects

glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
//Draw all open objects
```